# Validation using react hook form results in an error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hook-form

I am trying to use React Hook Form package in my form for validation and got this error when I refreshed the page. The idea is to collect the form input, validate it before sending to the server. However, I cannot get beyond this error message and don't know where to begin fixing it. Can Do you know how to fix it, if so - please help point me in the right direction on how to fix it?

My Form field

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

const login = () => {

    const {register, handleSubmit} = useForm();

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="min-h-screen bg-gray-50 flex flex-col justify-center py-12 sm:px-6 lg:px-8 bg-gradient-to-r from-gray-700 via-gray-800 to-gray-900">
            <div className="sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-md">
                <h2 className="mt-6 text-center text-3xl font-extrabold text-white">
                Sign in to your account
                </h2>
                <p className="mt-2 text-center text-sm text-gray-600 max-w">
                Or &nbsp;
                <a href="/register" className="font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500">
                    Register for an account
                </a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div className="mt-8 sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-md">
                <div className="bg-white py-8 px-4 shadow sm:rounded-lg sm:px-10">
                    {/* Form */}
                <form className="space-y-6" action="/login" method="POST" onSubmit={handleSubmit((data)=>{
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data))
                })}>
                    <div>
                    <label htmlFor="email" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                        Email address
                    </label>
                    <div className="mt-1">
                        <input ref={register} id="email" name="email" type="email" autoComplete="email" required className="appearance-none block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm placeholder-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm" />
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <label htmlFor="password" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                        Password
                    </label>
                    <div className="mt-1">
                        <input ref={register} id="password" name="password" type="password" autoComplete="current-password" required className="appearance-none block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm placeholder-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm" />
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
                    <div className="flex items-center">
                        <input ref={register} id="remember_me" name="remember_me" type="checkbox" className="h-4 w-4 text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-500 border-gray-300 rounded" />
                        <label htmlFor="remember_me" className="ml-2 block text-sm text-gray-900">
                        Remember me
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="text-sm">
                        <a href="#" className="font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500">
                        Forgot your password?
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <button type="submit" className="w-full flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent rounded-md shadow-sm text-sm font-medium text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
                        Sign in
                    </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div className="mt-6">
                    <div className="relative">
                    <div className="absolute inset-0 flex items-center">
                        <div className="w-full border-t border-gray-300" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="relative flex justify-center text-sm">
                        <span className="px-2 bg-white text-gray-500">
                        Or continue with
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="mt-6 grid grid-cols-2 gap-3">
                    <div>
                        <a href="#" className="w-full inline-flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm bg-white text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-50">
                        <span className="sr-only">Sign in with Google</span>
                            <img className="g-tile" src="/google-tile.png" />
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
</div>
    )
}
```

Error

> Unhandled Runtime Error
> TypeError: path.split is not a function

Call Stack

> ```
> get
> node_modules/react-hook-form/dist/index.esm.js (28:0)
> eval
> node_modules/react-hook-form/dist/index.esm.js (1426:0)
> commitAttachRef
> node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (20023:0)
> commitLayoutEffects
> node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (22808:0)
> HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback
> node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (188:0)
> Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev
> node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (237:0)
> invokeGuardedCallback
> node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (292:0)
> commitRootImpl
> node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (22541:0)
> unstable_runWithPriority
> node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (653:0)
> runWithPriority$1
> node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (11039:0)
> commitRoot
> node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (22381:0)
> finishSyncRender
> node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (21807:0)
> performSyncWorkOnRoot
> node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (21793:0)
> scheduleUpdateOnFiber
> node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (21188:0)
> updateContainer
> node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (24373:0)
> eval
> node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (24758:0)
> unbatchedUpdates
> node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (21903:0)
> legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer
> node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (24757:0)
> Object.hydrate
> node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (24823:0)
> renderReactElement
> node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js (530:6)
> doRender
> node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js (799:2)
> _callee2$
> node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js (425:10)
> tryCatch
> node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js (63:14)
> Generator.invoke [as _invoke]
> node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js (293:0)
> Generator.eval [as next]
> node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js (118:0)
> asyncGeneratorStep
> node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js (3:0)
> _next
> node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js (25:0)
> eval
> node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js (32:0)
> new Promise
> <anonymous>
> eval
> node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js (21:0)
> _render
> webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js (522:18)
> render
> webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js (459:18)
> eval
> node_modules/next/dist/client/next-dev.js (85:6)
> eval
> node_modules/next/dist/client/dev/fouc.js (14:6)
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason you are having this error is that you are using a different type of syntex. What version of react forms are you using? because there is a good chance you're are using v6 syntex on the newer v7 or vice-versa.

[V7 - React Hook Form](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register/)

[V6 - React Hook Form](https://react-hook-form.com/v6/api/#register)

It is probably because of the way you pass the ref for register, here is an example from the documentation on how to use it:

```
<input
  {...register("fieldname", {
      maxLength: 2
  })}
/>
```